# (Simple) Can HTML properties be attributes or are they only for CSS?

Tags: css, properties, attributes, svg

The [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties) talks about Properties.. what are these? Can they be declared as attributes inline with the element? .. or can they only be declared in CSS stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standards compliant are both. There are several reasons why to use the one or the other.

- The spec says, that CSS style declared properties always take precedence before the ones declared in XML attributes
- On the other hand, if you use attributes, you don't have the hassle to parse CSS declarations
- you can also declare an external stylesheet and style yur SVG from there

Styling properties, in short, are all these props, that are necessary for a certain rendering result, mostly related to color.

Equivalent examples:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="red"/>
<svg>
```

---

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect style="fill: red"/>
<svg>
```

---

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
    #fillme { fill: red; }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect id="fillme"/>
<svg>
```

Just note, that these CSS declarations are not valid in the sence of CSS specs 1 through 3.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

They can be set both inline and in a stylesheet, but to be standards compliant I would opt for declaration via an external stylesheet